# Changing state for input is delayed by one character (useState hook)

Tags: reactjs, input, state, react-hooks

I am trying to implement an instant search of user profiles in my social network. It seems to be working, but setting the state (using hooks) on input change results in delay by one character.

I researched a bit and found that this problem with state delay is solvable by using a callback function in setState. However, useState does not support that.

This is my input element:

```
<input
   type="text"
   placeholder="Enter your query"
   name="query"
   onChange={e => onChange(e)}
/>
```

This is my state and onChange handler:

```
const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState({
    query: "",
    filteredProfiles: profiles
  });


const onChange = e => {
    setFilteredData({
      query: e.target.value,
      filteredProfiles: profiles.filter(person =>
        person.user.name.includes(e.target.value)
      )
    });
    console.log(e.target.value); // outputs correct value immediately
    console.log(filteredData.query); // it's always one character late
    console.log(filteredData.filteredProfiles); //works but 1 char late as well
  };
```

Comment: It's not one character late, its the value prepared for this render, next value is for next render

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> it's always one character late

The console logs are within the previous state cycle so it's expected that it's "one cycle" late. Remember [**`setState()` is asynchronous**](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3).

If you want to log the current changes, use `useEffect` hook.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(filteredData.query); // not late
    console.log(filteredData.filteredProfiles); // same here!
  }, [filteredData]);
```

The effect hook will listen for current `filteredData` changes and log it.

Also I suggest using `useCallback` for event handlers.

Comment: Worth adding, that value from state is for current render, and nextValue is for next render, and if  you want to use nextValue in current render, you need useEffect

Answer (score 4):

Are you searching an API for this data, or are you searching local data?  Going off of your code, it seems like you're searching local data..

You can use `useEffect` to search through your data each time the input is changed.. This way the current state is used for your query.

The reason it is not working is because you are trying to set the state AND use that state in the same 'action', which will not work.. The state is "1 character behind" because it has not had the opportunity to update itself with the new results yet.. This is what `useEffect` helps with.

*Also, you don't **have** to use* `onChange={e => onChange(e)}` *in this scenario, but it doesn't hurt anything... You could just do* `onChange={onChange}` *and the event will be automatically passed as a parameter.*

Something like this should help..

[[CodePen Mirror]](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/wVmGMP)

```js
//// SCROLL DOWN FOR REACT CODE
const apiData = [
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: "delectus aut autem",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 2,
    title: "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 3,
    title: "fugiat veniam minus",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 4,
    title: "et porro tempora",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 5,
    title: "laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 6,
    title: "qui ullam ratione quibusdam voluptatem quia omnis",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 7,
    title: "illo expedita consequatur quia in",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    userId: 1,
    id: 8,
    title: "quo adipisci enim quam ut ab",
    completed: true
  }
];

function Searcher() {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState("et");
  const [results, setResults] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
      let searchResults;
      if (search) {
        searchResults = apiData.filter(i => i.title.includes(search));
      }
      setResults(searchResults);
    }, [search]);

  const handleInput = e => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Search Me!</h4>
      {/* You dont have to use "e=>handleInput(e)" in this scenario, but it
         doesn't hurt anything... */}
      <input type="text" value={search} onChange={e=>handleInput(e)} />
      <p>{search}</p>
      {search && results && results.length === 0 ? (
        <p>No results found!</p>
      ) : (
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(results, null, 2)}</pre>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Searcher />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing your function to the onChange handler instead of executing it? something like this:

```
<input
   type="text"
   placeholder="Enter your query"
   name="query"
   onChange={onChange} // Here
/>
```

In this way you don't generate a new function every time your component renders, hope it helps.