# input form doesn't register last character

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm looking to record the input files in one object to use the details in a graph. Everything works great but the first character I input it only generates the empty object thus the last character I input is not recorded in the object.

How can I get around this?

Project: https://github.com/fauxir/expense_chart_component

main Comp:

```html
import SpendingGraph from "./SpendingGraph";
import ThisMonth from "./ThisMonth";
import WeekInput from "./WeekInput";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { appear } from "/Users/Fauxir/Desktop/CSS-HTML-JS-REACT practice/expense_chart_component/src/redux/showSlice";

function MainComp() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});
  const see = useSelector((state) => state.show.value);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.placeholder]: e.target.value });
    //setDaySpending({...daySpending, [e.target.id]: e.target.value })
    console.log(values);
    //console.log(daySpending)
  };

  const inputs = [
    { placeholder: "Spent Monday", id: 1 },
    { placeholder: "Spent Tuesday", id: 2 },
    { placeholder: "Spent Wednesday", id: 3 },
    { placeholder: "Spent Thursday", id: 4 },
    { placeholder: "Spent Friday", id: 5 },
    { placeholder: "Spent Saturday", id: 6 },
    { placeholder: "Spent Sunday", id: 7 },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="bg-bridal-heath-500 w-80 h-fit rounded-lg flex flex-col items-center justify-between">
      {!see
        ? inputs.map((input) => (
            <WeekInput key={input.id} {...input} onInput={onChange} />
          ))
        : null}
      {see ? <SpendingGraph /> : null}
      {see ? <ThisMonth /> : null}
      <input onBlur={onChange}></input>
      {!see ? (
        <div
          onClick={() => dispatch(appear())}
          className="h-12 w-72 bg-terracotta-600  flex flex-row items-center justify-center rounded-md cursor-pointer mt-6 hover:bg-terracotta-500 hover:shadow-sambuca-300 hover:shadow-lg mb-8"
        >
          <div>Calculate</div>
        </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainComp;
```

Rendered input comp:

```html
function WeekInput(props) {
  const { placeholder, onChange, ...inputProps } = props;

  return (
    <div className="h-8 w-2/4 flex flex-col  justify-center mt-4">
      <input
        className="bg-bridal-heath-500 leading-none rounded-sm shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline text-gray-600 font-medium border-sambuca-300 border-2"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        {...inputProps}
        onChange={onChange}
      ></input>
    </div>
  );
}

export default WeekInput;
```

Comment: no `value` prop ?

Comment: The value prop works just fine. The issue is when passing what you're typing the first character is just creating the object. You could say that every time you type something the object records everything except your last character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the `onChange` function as props named `onInput` and using it as `onChange`. 
So you have to change the name of props `onInput` to `onChange` like below.

```js
// MainComp
<WeekInput key={input.id} {...input} onChange={onChange} />
```

#### **Update**

Add `useEffect` to synchronize state.

```js
// MainComp
  useEffect(() => {
    setValues(values);
  }, [values]);
```

#### **FYI**

- [Changing state for input is delayed by one character (useState hook)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403647/changing-state-for-input-is-delayed-by-one-character-usestate-hook)

Comment: onChange was my first try and then I started to play around...still the same result. Looks like the object that registers the inputs is always one character behind.

Comment: @MihaiTohaneanu Does the delay only happen on the console or on the component?

Comment: useEffect will sort it out. Thanks! Every day is a school day.